# Testing PPPoA using WICs

Tags: cisco, adsl

We've started deploying cisco routers in pairs (867VAE-K9 in particular) to offer office sites failover using ip sla and HSRP.

In testing I've been using 1841s and running the dialer over ethernet instead of adsl to confirm it works 95% but I don't have spare dsl lines to confirm it works with the comlete config that gets deployed so we test with PPPoE dialer and then adjust slightly when installed.

I have an 1841 set up to act as PPPoE server and that works peachy. I'd like to use the same box to simulate a dsl line instead and I kind of think you can do some back to back stuff with a WIC 1SHDSL V3. But it looks like I need to use the same card at each end. I want to be able to configure a wic-1adsl at the other end or use the built in dsl connection on one of the 867s. Is it possible and can someone point to a suitable reference to do this? Or does it need to be shdsl cards at both ends for a back to back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done - I misunderstood DSL technologies. It's not like Ethernet / FastEthernet / GigE where they all work together at different rates.

2 x SHDSL cards can be configured as a back to back connection but ADSL won't co-operate on a line with SHDSL.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.